# Ada Get_Line not waiting to get Response

Tags: ada

I have this strange problem in a program I have been working on. If I attempt to use get_line in Ada to solicit a response from the use after already doing a previous Q&A, the program does not wait for the response. I have put together a little demo program that replicates the issue. I can not use an unbounded string in my situation. I have instructions to use a bound string.

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO; USE Ada.Text_IO;

PROCEDURE StrPractice IS
   Name : String (1 .. 5);
   NextName : String (1 .. 10);
   Len  : Natural;

BEGIN
   Put("Enter first name? "); --5 digit terry
   Get(Name);
   new_line;
   Put_line("First Name: " & name);
   New_Line;

   Put("Enter next name:");
   Get_Line(NextName, Len);
   new_line(2);
   Put_Line("Next name: " & NextName(1..Len));
END StrPractice;
```

I am not sure what is causing this problem. I thought perhaps the buffer needed clearing, so I crated a character variable c and used get(c), but that did not correct my issue. I did a search here, but did not see the same situation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You undoubtely are hitting Enter after you enter the `Name`, but `Get` does not consume the end-of-line.  So it's still there in the buffer when you call `Get_Line` later.  Try adding a call to `Skip_Line` to consume the end-of-line.

Comment: Bless you! Yep, That corrected the issue. I figured it was grabbing my enter, but for the life of me, could not figure out how to deal with it. Thank you very much!

Comment: OK, then I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you enter the `Name`, you have to enter a newline before the program can see your input.  However, `Get` does not consume the newline; thus, when `Get_Line` is called, it sees the newline still in the input buffer and treats that as the end of the input line.  You can consume the newline by using `Skip_Line`:

```
Put("Enter first name? "); --5 digit terry
Get(Name);
Skip_Line;
new_line;
Put_line("First Name: " & name);
New_Line;
```